# Copy to clipboard in A/B Testing tool

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

im new to JQuery and a A/B testing tool called Convert. In one of the experiments, I want to add a small piece of text that when a user clicks on it it will copy the text to the clipboard and will show a tooltip saying "Copied!" but for some reason the code is not working, it doesn't shows an eroor, it's like it doesn't even run. I can't find an error and I'm not sure if it may be the tool who is giving me problems but would like somebody with more experience to take a look and tell if I did something wrong to know how to improve.

Here's the HTML:

```
<a id="copy-promo-btn" href="#">PLUS79</a>
```

This is the CSS:

```
.copy-notification {
        color: #ffffff;
        background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
        padding: 20px;
        border-radius: 30px;
        position: fixed;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        width: 150px;
        margin-top: -30px;
        margin-left: -85px;
        display: none;
        text-align:center;}
```

And this is the javascript:

```js
convert.$(document).ready(function() {
   $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#copy-promo-btn").click(function (event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                CopyToClipboard("PLUS79", true, "Copied!");
            });
        });

        function CopyToClipboard(value, showNotification, notificationText) {
            var $temp = $("<input>");
            $("body").append($temp);
            $temp.val(value).select();
            document.execCommand("copy");
            $temp.remove();

            if (typeof showNotification === 'undefined') {
                showNotification = true;
            }
            if (typeof notificationText === 'undefined') {
                notificationText = "Copied!";
            }

            var notificationTag = $("div.copy-notification");
            if (showNotification && notificationTag.length == 0) {
                notificationTag = $("<div/>", { "class": "copy-notification", text: notificationText });
                $("body").append(notificationTag);

                notificationTag.fadeIn("slow", function () {
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        notificationTag.fadeOut("slow", function () {
                            notificationTag.remove();
                        });
                    }, 1000);
                });
            }
        }
});
```

Comment: In convert documentation: https://support.convert.com/hc/en-us/articles/114094183412-Variation-Code-FAQ, it says that if you are introducing custom javascript that will manipulate DOM elements it needs to be wrapped in a DOM ready call: convert.$(document).ready(function() {
   //code here
}); or that is what I understood

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you can copy to clipboard your text on click event by adding some java-script to your existing code.

`.select()` will not work in your case because its ONLY selects the text but its does not copy it which in your case you need to click to copy and paste as well.

Few things added:

1. You need to create element in body and copy your text value into it
2. Once it copied successfully it will delete the input value from DOM

Run snippet below to see it working.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#copy-promo-btn").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    CopyToClipboard("PLUS79");
  });
});


function CopyToClipboard(value) {
  var copyvalue = document.createElement('input');
  copyvalue.value = value
  document.body.appendChild(copyvalue);
  copyvalue.select();
  document.execCommand('copy');
  console.log(copyvalue.value)
  document.body.removeChild(copyvalue);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="copy-promo-btn" href="#">PLUS79</a>
```